# Unable to understand Google Games Quests time zone selection

Tags: android, datetime, google-play-games

I am unable to understand how does google Quests API (Games.Quests)  decide which quest to be open in different time zones and when.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests#quest_basics

In the above link it says

> **Schedule** Specifies when players will be able to accept and participate in quests. When you enter the dates and time values, Google Play games services uses your local time zone but stores the values as UTC. Players will see these values appear in their local time zone in the Google Play Games app and in the default Quest list UI. You can also set up a quest as a repeating event on a weekly or monthly basis.

But unable to understand how schedule works.
**For example : If as a Developer I have set time according to India (+5:30 UTC) and set that a quest will end on 12:00 am. Then when will the quest end in Mexico (-6:00 UTC)?**

Note : The Quests list(with time & state) in Google Play Games app (as said above) remains the same even on changing device's time or time zone.

Comment: This is basic dealing with timezones -  nothing complicated going on here. 12:00 AM in UTC+05:30 is equal to 00:30 on UTC-06:00.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you think you have to do anything at all to make this work with timezones? You don't. Google does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Hi @XaverKapeller Thanks for the comment. I just want to know how does Google determines which Player gets which quest open and when?. And, Basically I want that when I say a Quest will end on 12:00 am. Then it should end on 12:00 am everywhere, irrespective of their time zone.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Xaver, Goggle does all the heavy lifting for you. When you create a quest for the game and enter the dates and time values, Google Play games services uses your local time zone but stores the values as UTC as stated in the document. Google Play games will show this in the local timezone of the user.

For example you set the end of the quest in 12:am in India, then in Mexico it will end 12:30 PM.

[image]

The image is provided by 
https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?p1=54&p2=155 and it will help you understand more how the timezone works in Google Play Games Quest timezone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Rebot, Thanks for the answer :). It helps. But I really want to know how does google determine which player gets which quest. I mean does google get players current location, or does google uses players country (which s/he may have set when creating profile), or something else. And If possible, I want that when I say a Quest will end on 12:00 am. Then it should end on 12:00 am (for e.g. 12:00 am in Mexico & not 12:30 pm) everywhere, irrespective of their time zone.